# unserialize data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

in my mysql cell this is stored using serialize function

```
a:1:{i:0;s:275:"a:4:{s:8:"khghg_id";s:10:"foo1187";s:3:"uri";s:21:"foo/vtory/1187";s:4:"name";s:5:"nmart";s:5:"tuhlmb";a:3:{i:0;s:40:"knuujhs/201205/13_03_pceb9.jpg";i:1;s:40:"knuujhs/201205/13_03_0wlih.jpg";i:2;s:40:"knuujhs/201205/13_03_tq5wf.jpg";}}";}
```

i am trying to do unserialize

i am using this code

```
$cell =$row9['attachment'];
$list = unserialize($cell);
$info = unserialize($list[0]);
var_dump($info);
```

when i am trying with this i am getting error bool(false) error
so i tried with parse_str
with parse_str i did not get any error

```
 parse_str($cell,$list );
```

but i am not getting the output in my database 
i am storing the output in database and i am submitting the query to database .everything is getting stored other than this unserialize values .here u can note that there are

khghg_id which is foo1187
uri  which is foo/vtory/1187
name which is nmart
i want to store these details in my database so i am using

```
'.$info['khghg_id'].'   for sending the data to mysql but mysql stores everything  other than  all unsterilized  values
```

Comment: You should actually store `serialize()`ed value in database and when you fetch it `unserialize()` it.

Comment: data are stored in serialize form i am unseralizing it and again storing universalized values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You retrieve a serialized text from database.

You unserialize it.. change it and then when you save it back to database you need to serialize it back

```
//retrieve serialized data from database
$arr = unserialize($row['properties']);

//get the desired value
$khghg_id = $arr['khghg_id'];

//now insert $khghg_id in database
```

From the code you posted above.. I see you are unserializing 2 times.. you dont really need to do this

```
$cell =$row9['attachment'];
$list = unserialize($cell);
$info = $list[0]; //this line should make the difference
var_dump($info);
```

Comment: i am able to get full serialize values i have tested and it shows full string . i want to break it into parts and want to store only few values from unserialized values .in my case i want to store only '.$info['khghg_id'].' value in database in mycode where i am doing mistake can u please tell

Comment: you want to store `$info['khghg_id']` in the same field? or a different field?

Comment: error is coming NULL and nothing is inserted into database again

Comment: What do you get on `var_dump(unserialize($cell));` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11190/discussion-between-steeve-and-broncha)